# Adding Empty Document to Couchbase bucket

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

As context, I am creating a bucket of key values with empty documents to fulfill a want to quickly check IDs just through checking key existence in comparison to checking values. In the cluster, I have two buckets, source-bucket and new-bucket. The documents in source-bucket are in the form:

```
ID: {
ID: ...,
type: ...
}
```

You can move the contents of source to the new bucket using the query

```
INSERT INTO `new-bucket` (KEY k, VALUE v) SELECT meta(v).id AS k FROM `source-bucket` as v
```

Is there a way to copy over just the key? Something along the lines of this (although this example doesn't work):

```
INSERT INTO `new-bucket` (KEY k, VALUE v) values (SELECT meta().id FROM `source-bucket`, NULL)
```

I guess I'm not familiar enough with the n1ql syntax to under how to construct a query like this. Let me know if you have an answer to this. If this is a duplicate, feel free to point to the answer.

Comment: What version of Couchbase are you using? I tried your first query, and that actually resulted in null valued documents in new-bucket. So I think you're on the right track, except it's a little awkward to us `v` twice, that may be confusing. `insert into new-bucket (KEY k, VALUE v)
SELECT meta(b).id AS k
FROM source-bucket b` I think gives you what you want (I had to omit back ticks for this comment)

Comment: Thanks for your awesome comment! Would that query allow give me null valued documents?

Comment: query also give me*

Comment: Ignore that question, I understand the query now. However, I am running into an error code 4000 because there are no index in source-bucket. The cluster is data and data/query nodes

Comment: for that query, I think you'll need a primary index, unfortunately: `CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON source-bucket` (again, with backticks around the bucket name)

Answer (score 2):

If you need empty object use {}.

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON `source-bucket`;

INSERT INTO `new-bucket` (KEY k, VALUE {}) 
SELECT meta(b).id AS k FROM `source-bucket` as b
```

NOTE: document value can be empty object or any data type. The following all are valid.

```
  INSERT INTO default VALUES ("k01", {"a":1});
  INSERT INTO default VALUES ("k02", {});
  INSERT INTO default VALUES ("k03", 1);
  INSERT INTO default VALUES ("k04", "aa");
  INSERT INTO default VALUES ("k05", true);
  INSERT INTO default VALUES ("k06", ["aa"]);
  INSERT INTO default VALUES ("k07", NULL);
```